Orientation via homology and via differential forms
On a smooth manifold $M$ of dimension $n$, all the following definitions make sense:

An orientation form or volume form is an element $\omega \in \Omega^n(M)$ which is never $0$
A manifold is said to be orientable if there exists an atlas compatible with the differential structure on $M$ such that the change of coordinates maps always have jacobian with positive determinant
Hatcher says $M$ is orientable if there exists a choice of a local orientation $\mu_x \in H_n(M | x) := H_n(M,M\smallsetminus {x})$ such that a local consistency condition is satisfied: for every $x \in M$ there esists a coordinate ball $B$ in $M$ centered in $x$ and an element $\mu_B \in H_n(M|U)$ such that for every $y \in B$, $\mu_y$ is the image of $\mu_B$ via the map $H_n(M|B) \rightarrow H_n(M|y)$ given by inclusion.  This is the same as considering the presheaf $\mathcal{F}$ on $M$ which assigns to each open set $U \subseteq M$ the group $H_n(M|U)$ and saying that an orientation for $M$ is an element of the sheafification of $\mathcal{F}$ which generates each stalk $\mathcal{F}_x$.

The equivalence of the first 2 definitions is very standard, my problem comes with the third. While I understand the definition, I was hoping to be able to prove the equivalence with one of the former ones. I formulated it in terms of sheaves hoping that could give me an hint linking it to the sheaf of top forms, but I'm at a dead end. Some help?

I don't think going from 2 to 3 should be so hard: Every coordinate ball $B \subset M$ defines two elements $\mu_B, \mu'B$ (namely the two generators of $H_n(M \mid B) \cong \mathbb{Z}$ which restrict to generators $\mu_x, \mu'x$ for each $x \in B$, so the only question is whether there is a coherent choice of balls ${B_i}{i \in I}$ covering $M$ together with generators ${\mu{B_i}}{i \in I}$ such that $\mu{B_i}$ and $\mu_{B_j}$ pull back to the same generator $\mu_x$ whenever $x \in B_i \cap B_j$.

Thus, if you use condition 2 to cover $M$ by charts with domain a coordinate ball such that the transition maps have positive determinant, then all you need to do is some "translation" work (from "positive jacobi determinant" to "induces identity in homology"), i.e. show that this condition gives exactly the compatibility of pullbacks I outlined above. I think it would be good for you to try your hand at this and update the question with how far you can get. You might get some additional inspiration from Hatcher's "Orientations and Homology" subsection (pp. 233).

Here's a sketch:
For a homeomorphism $f\colon U\rightarrow V$ between open sets $U,V\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$, call it topologically orientation-preserving if the induced map $H_n(U|u)\rightarrow H_n(V|f(u))$ takes the canonical local orientation to the canonical local orientation for any $u\in U$.
Then, prove these facts:

A diffeomorphism $f\colon U\rightarrow V$ between open sets $U,V\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ is topologically orientation-preserving iff it is orientation-preserving in the usual sense, i.e. its Jacobian has every positive determinant. [Hint: W.l.o.g. asssume $u=f(u)=0$ and use the homotopy $(t,x)\mapsto f(tx)/t\text{ if }t>0, df_0(x)\text{ if }t=0$ to reduce to the case where $f$ is linear, then use that $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{R})$ has $2$ path-components.]

The manifold $M$ is orientable in the sense of Hatcher iff it admits a topologically orientable atlas, i.e. an atlas whose transition maps are topologically orientation-preserving. More precisely, if $M$ admits a consistent choice of local orientations, then any atlas can be changed into a topologically orientable atlas by at most post-composing the restriction of each chart to a component of its domain by a reflection if necessary [in particular, a smooth atlas remains smooth under this procedure].


Together, these facts imply the second and third definition are equivalent.

Do you know anything about checking equivalence (for non-differentiable manifolds) with the cohomological definitions of orientation? If $M$ is any topological $n$-manifold then it can be shown $\mathfrak{or}{M,R}:U\mapsto\hom_R(H^n_C(U;R),R)$ is a sheaf for any Noetherian ring $R$. Following Iversen I may define a manifold as $R$-orientable iff. this locally constant sheaf is in fact globally constant; an $R$-orientation is a choice of isomorphism of $R$-sheaves $\underline{R}\cong\mathfrak{or}{M,R}$. It's a headache, for $R=\Bbb Z$, to relate that (especially in the noncompact case) with

With Hatcher's homological orientation notion

@FShrike Hmm, I'm not familiar with that definition (and it's not clear to me that is in fact a sheaf). However, if it's a locally constant sheaf, it is globally constant iff it admits a non-trivial global section, but (assuming $M$ connected), $H_c^n$ is $\mathbb{Z}$ or $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ depending on whether $M$ is orientable or not, so that establishes the equivalence (granted, this calculation requires Poincaré duality).

I believe it is globally constant iff. its global section module is nonzero only in the case of $R$ a field. Taking a nonzero global section $s$ we find a map $\underline{R}\to\mathfrak{or}_{M,R}$ and we wish for it to be an isomorphism on all stalks, ie for $s_x$ to be a unit for all $x$, and that wouldn’t be guaranteed just from the observation (assuming connectivity) $s_x$ is always nonzero

I’ve revently been trying to marry Iversen’s treatment of Poincaré duality, which is very sheafy and cohomological, with more classical and homological notions. I don’t yet have perfect progress :) but I have shown, I think, Iversen-orientability over the integers implies Hatcher orientability.

@FShrike Fair point, I was a bit too quick there. It's not immediately clear to me what the stalks of this sheaf are, but if you can calculate them and they behave as expected, the argument works. In the non-orientable case, the global sections are torsion, hence cannot be a unit in each stalk, and, in the orientable case, the calculation of the top cohomology should demonstrate the generator corresponds to a section that is a stalkwise unit. This argument does feel a bit backwards to me, but so does this definition of the orientation sheaf (that's probably just my ignorance, though).

This definition of orientation sheaf arises very naturally from Verdier duality. The only other definition I've seen (which was recently, on this site, from the op) is the sheafification of $U\mapsto H_n(M|U)$ which, you know, requires sheafification and therefore has unclear sections. That this definition of orientation sheaf is actually a sheaf is a happy miracle, but it also falls very cleanly out of Verdier duality : ) it is also general beyond manifolds; the definition holds for, say, any $n$-dimensional CW complex (the sheaf just may not be locally constant any more)

For a manifold without boundary, this sheaf has stalk $R$ at every point. Anyway, if I buy that calculation $H^n_c=\Bbb Z,,\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$ then you're right, they would turn out to be equivalent.
